# Google Maps Marker Drag End Directions - Clear Previous Route

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API v3, and I have implemented a directions rendered based on a marker drag end function. But if you drag the marker again then the original set of directions are not removed.

The map is generated based of a geocoding request and autocomplete textbox for source and the destination is static. This all works fine. I have read the API documentation and it says use the .setMap(null); option but it is not clearing the directions, and I believe this is because I am not regenerating the map. My code for the rendering of the directions is below:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(markersrc, 'dragend', function () {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': markersrc.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var request = {
                origin: markersrc.getPosition(),
                destination: markerdst.getPosition(),
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            directionsDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions_panel"));
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Anyone have any idea how I can get the original directions cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that each time you drag the marker, you recreate the DirectionsDisplay and DirectionsService.  Instead I think you need to create those as global variables, which only get updated by the dragend event listener.